# Google oauth is working on localhost but not on my web server

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

Just an interest into google oauth.

Google has three basic scopes you can access, email, openid and profile. When building this into my website locally all three of the scopes work. However I uploaded the website onto my server today and when I tried to authenticate through the google oauth and it brought back error 403 (forbidden). When I removed the profile from the scope it worked awesome!!

How come 'profile' works on local websites but not on sever-side websites? I have researched all day into this and found something about using the google+ api, but I don't know where to place the key in my application.

The 'openid' and the 'email' works so I can do a work around on the site, however any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the URLs in your google cloud project crendentials, and in the google passport strategy in your nodejs server[image]